# How ta call function in my case?

Tags: javascript

I have such construction:

```
<a href="some.jpg"><img src="other.jpg" onclick="someAction(this);"></a>
<a href="some2.jpg"><img src="other2.jpg" onclick="someAction(this);"></a>
<a href="some3.jpg"><img src="other3.jpg" onclick="someAction(this);"></a>
```

When I try to add alert(this) to onclick, I get [object HTMLImageElement]

I need to call this someAction for exact image from  in other part of page

How to do this?

Comment: That's because `this` is the HTML Image element...what do you want from it?

Comment: Looks like everything works fine! (actually, you haven't really explained where `alert(this)` is nor what you want to do).

Comment: someAction loads large image into div, than changes css of small image. I want to do this using <select>. I need to call someAction from select. But I don't know, what must be in brackets

Comment: Give the images an id, pass that to the function then you can use (this.id) or ("theid") elsewhere

Comment: *"But I don't know, what must be in brackets"* Judging from the way you are calling the function now, you have to pass a DOM element.

Answer (score 2):

Add an id to each image element, and call the function by using element id, this way:

```
<a href="some.jpg"><img id="img1" src="other.jpg" onclick="someAction(this.id);"></a>
<a href="some2.jpg"><img id="img1" src="other2.jpg" onclick="someAction(this.id);"></a>
<a href="some3.jpg"><img id="img1" src="other3.jpg" onclick="someAction(this.id);"></a>
```

Then change your function as following:

```
function someAction(senderId){
   var sender = document.getElementById(senderId);
   // ...use sender variable as you did before
}
```

Now you can call the same function wherever you like to in the page, eg:

```
<div onclick="someAction('img2')">Foo</div>"
```

Comment: Why not just pass a DOM element to the function, `someAction(document.getElementById('img2'))`? It depends which scenario is more common, but that seems to make more sense than querying the DOM for the element if you already have a reference to it.

Comment: @Felix: You have your points, but this is an endless question: should I prefer to add a bit of overhead by getting references (my answer) or maybe add a bit of tag-scripting in html elements, losing readability (your comment)? That depends, as ever. I would then prefer to transform the function this way: someAction(sender, senderId). If sender is null, then get sender variable by its id. You can then call the fn as someAction(this) or either someAction(null,'id')

Comment: Anyway, i wouldn't change my answer if performance isn't critical, as in 99.9% of situations. Otherwise, no one would use JQuery selectors, iterators, and so on.

Comment: Almost working.. I use MagicZoom. How to load large image from <select>? Maybe I must simulate click on small image?

Comment: I don't know what MagicZoom is, and cannot understand your comment.

Comment: I'm talking to myself :) I've found solution for my problem. Thanks evereyone

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your image an `id="some_id"` and then reference that in your function call:

```
   onClick="someAction(document.getElementById(\"some_id\"))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a reference to the `<img/>` element. There are multiple ways to get a reference to a DOM node (e.g., `document.getElementById`, `document.getElementsByTagName`, `document.getElementsByClassName`, etc).

For example:

```
var firstImg = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
someAction(firstImg);
```

Furthermore, you should probably bind your `click` handler to the anchor instead of the image as the browser will likely follow the `href` on the anchor before it executes your image's `click` handler.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Every img had it's id. I've changed to onclick="someAction(document.getElementById('id'));", added to <select> same changes - the css of small image changes. But large image doesn't load. Must find what else to change in this script